# Получать конкретное разрешение для устройства

Tags: android, kotlin

Как можно улучшить данный метод, который конвертирует `px` в `dp`?

```
fun convertPixelsToDp(px: Float, context: Context): Float {
    val resources = context.resources
    val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH)
    return dp
}
```

Так как значение `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH` не хочется выносить в константу, да и скорей всего можно как-то более лучшим образом получать разрешения экрана устройств.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
fun convertPixelsToDp(px: Float, context: Context): Float {
    val resources = context.resources
    val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
    var dp =  px / (metrics.density / metrics.densityDpi)
    return dp
}
```